# Не заводится PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, debian

Установлена последняя доступная версия (9.3). systemctl сервис не видел, но после перезапуска непосредственно через init-скрипт демон СУБД появился. Тем не менее, подключиться к ней всё так же не получается.

```
createdb: не удалось подключиться к базе postgres: не удалось подключиться к серверу: Нет такого файла или каталога
    Он действительно работает локально и принимает
    соединения через доменный сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

В /var/run/postgresql только 9.3-main.pid

Comment: Проверьте, что в /etc/postgresql/9.1./main/postgresql.conf есть строка unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql' в секции 'connection settings' (если нет - добавьте).

> В /var/run/postgresql только 9.3-main.pid

Просто на всякий случай спрошу: флаг -a команды ls не забыли?

Comment: Забыл._. Оно висело на 5433-порту - видимо, из-за конфликта с предыдущей версией. Но теперь там другая проблема:

createdb: не удалось подключиться к базе template1: ВАЖНО:  роль "root" не существует

Я чего-то недокурил по начальной настройке?

Comment: @MiniRoboDancer не совсем по настройке. Постгре - хитрая штука, которая из коробки подразумевает, что пользователь будет заходить под своим именем, и как в мускуле под рутом с паролем зайти вообще не получится. Вход от суперпользователя делается так: `sudo -u postgres psql`, что выполнит команду от пользователя постгрес (а он входит без пароля). Политики доступа меняются в файле pg_hba.conf.